# Exception EExternalException in module ntdll.dll at 000xxxxx. External exception C0000026

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Ao tentar depurar um software no Embarcadero XE2 ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Exception EExternalException in module ntdll.dll at 000xxxxx. External exception C0000026
```

Percebi que isso ocorreu após atualizar para o Update 4.

Comment: Estava com o mesmo problema!
Deu certinho aqui! obrigado!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

- Removi o AQTimer
- Abri o registro: *HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Debugging\Embarcadero Debuggers\Evaluators* e dentro deste no arquivo *comp32x.dll*  mudei seu valor de 1 para -1
- Reiniciei o Embarcadero

Fonte: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118091